# Extension methods not compiling

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, extension-methods

**Consider the following simple Extension method:**

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int DemoLength(this string str, string toAdd)
    {
        return (str + toAdd).Length;
    }
}
```

I have to possibilities to call it:

1. With the extension

   `int result1 = "hello".DemoLength("all");`
2. From the static class

   `int result2 = MyExtensions.DemoLength("hello", "all");`

**Now consider an other example:**

```
IQueryable<int> source = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).AsQueryable();
Expression<Func<int, bool>> expr = t => (t & 1) == 0; // Even numbers
LambdaExpression lambda = expr;
```

1. With the extension

   `IQueryable<int> result1 = source.Where((dynamic)lambda);`
2. From the static class

   `IQueryable<int> result2 = Queryable.Where(source, (dynamic)lambda);`

Why would the extension method ***not compile*** this time?

Comment: The compiler message actually *tells* you exactly why it won't compile... just sayin'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `dynamic` does not use extension methods, and even though the C# compiler knows this is a `dynamic` operation and *could* defer the entire thing to runtime, it also knows that there is no `Where` method that will ever work here.

The compiler tells us all of this (taken from compiling the code in your example):

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' has no applicable method named 'Where' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

The `Queryable.Where` version works because it is no longer using an extension method.

To illustrate with a simple example:

```
static void Extension<T>(this string s, T t) {}
static void Main()
{
    string s = "";
    int i = 123;
    s.Extension(i); // fine
    s.Extension((dynamic)i); // doesn't compile; 
}
```

In particular, note the compiler message:

> 'string' has no applicable method named 'Extension' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.